# Turning WebBrowser.Print() into a blocking function

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, webbrowser-control

I'm using C# winforms to develop a software, and making use of a **WebBrowser** control. I've realized that the `Print()` function is non-blocking, but i need to execute a function before and after the printing process. Is there any way to check for a printed event, or any other attributes that could let me stop the execution of the program until the printing as been done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Print function should only add a job to the printqueue of the computer and will be done very fast. However using System.Printing.PrintServer and System.Printing.PrintQueue classes you might be able.

1. use `new PrintServer()` to get a instance for your local computer.
2. then use `GetPrintQueues()` on the instance to get all local queues.
3. then iterate the queues and check their `NumberOfJobs` property to check if any item still needs to be printed.

if you want an event you'd actually have to implement that event yourself. like:

```
public static event Action OnEmptyPrintQueue;
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Task(() =>
    {
        var wasEmpty = true;
        while (true)
        {
            if (wasEmpty && NumberOfJobs > 0)
            {
                wasEmpty = false;
            }
            else if (!wasEmpty && NumberOfJobs == 0)
            {
                wasEmpty = true;
                OnEmptyPrintQueue?.Invoke();
            }
        }

    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I needed ! I'm actually using this feature to save an HTML document as a PDF, do you know if there's any way to get the Path to the actual saved file (WebBrowser.Print() doesn't return anything)

Comment: I'm trying to attach an Event to the "NumberOfJobs" property value change, but it's an internal set property and I can't manage to set it properly, any idea ?

Comment: good question, i don't know exactly and that should actually be implementation specific. but the default folder should be "My Documents" and the filename should be something like the document title so probably the file can be accessible by using something like
`Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), (string)browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.title.toString()"));`
where `browser` is the webbrowser control instance